# Developer ID signed OS X app crashes on start with Code Signature Invalid

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing

I'm trying to build my app such that I can share it with testers. My app specifies entitlements (iCloud) so I have to sign it. To distribute a signed build I think I need to sign it using 'Developer ID', which I've done. The app package appears to be signed correctly - running:

```
spctl --verbose=4 --assess --type execute <my app>
```

reports:

```
<my app>: accepted
source=Developer ID
```

But when I run the app it crashes - a 'Code Signature Invalid' exception.

So why does it crash? I think I need to include the provisioning profile I've created which includes the UUID's for my tester's machines, but when I try to export the 'Developer ID-signed Application' from Xcode it always lists the provisioning profile as 'None', and there's no way to change it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out that I was misunderstanding a bunch of things.

Firstly - I'm pretty sure it crashes because although the code signature is valid, I'm trying to use features (iCloud) which are only available to apps downloaded from the app store; the app needs to be signed by Apple to run.

Secondly - Developer ID-signed apps don't use provisioning profiles; these are production-ready apps for actual distribution outside of the app store (so long as they don't use app-store only features).

So how do I share a build so that testers can run it and use its iCloud features? The answer is I build a development build as I normally do, signed as a developer, but create a matching provisioning profile including the UUIDs of my tester's machines. I then export the archived app using 'Export as Mac Application'. Both the app AND the profile need to be passed on to testers - they can install the profile by simply double-clicking on it to bring up the profile manager.

This took me a few hours to figure out - I don't think it's clear from the doc quite how all these things relate, so I hope this is useful to someone! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I recommended to create DMG file and put the app in Application folder:

this is clean and build the proj:

```
xcodebuild   -configuration Release -scheme {SCHEME_NAME} clean build
```

and create the dmg file:

```
hdiutil create -volname {PROJECT_NAME} -srcfolder {...}/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug/{APP_NAME}}.app -ov -format UDZO {SRC_PATH_FORDMG_FILE}/{PRODUCT_NAME}.dmg
```