# Team Provisioning Profile-signed OS X app crashes with Code Signature Invalid error

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I have an in-house OS X app that I want to share with my co-workers. My app uses Maps, so therefore I need to codesign it otherwise Maps feature doesn't work.

I'm signing my app with my team provisioning profile, containing Hardware UUID's of all our Macs:

[image]

We are 4 people. On my Mac and one of my friends' Mac, it runs perfectly. On the other two, they are getting a codesign error:

`EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)`

I've seen [Mac OS X app crash with Code Signature Invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994343/mac-os-x-app-crash-with-code-signature-invalid-error) and [Developer ID signed OS X app crashes on start with Code Signature Invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509809/developer-id-signed-os-x-app-crashes-on-start-with-code-signature-invalid) and I'm doing everything the same as they've done there. Why are they getting invalid code signature error and how can I avoid that error (while still letting maps feature run on their device, so no codesigning is not an option)?

Comment: Which version of `OS X` is the machine using you are doing the code-signing on?

Comment: @l'L'l 10.10.3, latest.

Comment: Okay, then that rules that out. Older versions of `OS X` (before 10.9+) can't sign apps used on newer versions. Is everyone running the same exact version of `OS X` - just curious.

Comment: Well, I know everyone is on Yosemite, but I don't know about their minor version. I'll learn it, but I heavily doubt that would cause an invalid code signature error.

Comment: True, likely makes no difference. The only other thing I can recommend is to check the member center and verify that the team provisioning profiles for those other devices haven't expired, or are still valid.

Comment: @l'L'l I've triple checked the provisioning profile. They are valid on the Apple Dev Center, my Mac Developer Program membership is valid, and I've deleted/refreshed all the provisioning profiles automatically from the dev portal within Xcode 6.3. I've got the Hardware UUID's just the day before, it's impossible for anything to be expired.

Comment: It might be a bug then and would recommend reporting it, because it sounds to me as if you've done everything correctly.

Comment: @l'L'l I will. Then I'll try deleting all the profiles, re-checking hardware UUID's quadruple checking that I'm codesigning with the correct profile/certificate, restart Xcode and my Mac, clean build folder and DerivedData folder, and try again, as I have no other options, I guess.

Comment: The *only* other thing I just thought of (although I'm not sure this would affect it) would be the gatekeeper settings on the other machines (eg. `Allow apps downloaded from`)

Comment: FWIW, if you open application package, and then open the "embedded.provisionprofile" file with TextEdit, some of the file is encoded as a plist.  One of the keys is "ProvisionedDevices", and the value is an array of strings of the UUID's the application can run on.  In my case, I discovered it did not include the UUID for one of my testing devices.  After confirming that UUID was in the device list in the developer portal, I refreshed the provisioning profile in Xcode, fixing the problem.

Comment: I found the same thing as @jbaraga – thank you.  This crash indicating "Invalid Code Signature" is misleading.  I submitted this to bugreport.apple.com.  Bug 33266115.